# Sucesión de Fibonacci hasta que sea menor o igual que N

Tags: java, fibonacci

Necesito hacer una sucesión de Fibonacci utilizando un algoritmo recursivo que se realice hasta que la sucesión sea menor o igual a N. El problema es que se excede del valor N. Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento. Gracias de antemano

```
if(n == 0 || n == 1){ 
        return n;
    }else{
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
    }

int n = 10; 
System.out.println("Secuencia de Fibonacci hasta " + n + ":");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.print(fibonacci(i) + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Cambia el `<=` por `<`. Si te refieres a otra cosa no veo ningún problema https://tio.run/##bVA7b8IwEJ6TX/HJk60IBB1LWbt1ylgxGMehR8MFxQ4SAn57ekkLpIiT/Lo7f4/b2oOdbIvvrtu364ocXGVDwIclxilNIfFXCNFGOYgjSlrXbJ0j3b/YSGeSDL19UAnNWC4xw/mM4TY3J9zqfTQ@tg2DF7fsBb4KXpCetN35eDI3yP4lXswIJP3dn@g@1FRgJ7Z0HhvizecKttkEM2IczEDUzhZ3tfkxRL@b1m2c7uVfrFir3LvWsyOLwuP9qgVfVrigRB/LUq9qpKysGwzTIiEQfMKbuAdlmXnw/EioR9PuvSv0uMnV6qXrfgA

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo aquí el código que hice yo(creo que es más fácil de entender y más eficiente):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    
    fibonacci(0, 1, 5);
}

public static int fibonacci(int num1, int num2, int n){
    if(n == 0 || n == 1){
        return n;
    }
    if(n <= num2){
        return num2;
    }
    int aux = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = num2 + aux;
    System.out.println(num2);
    return fibonacci(num1, num2, n);
}
```

En este caso se comprueba que el numero actual sea mayor o igual al número que pediste, si esto ocurre, acaba el programa, creo que ese era tu fallo. No comprobabas con el =
Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Si bien el problema se soluciona, no explicas por qué. Agrega una pequeña explicación a la respuesta para que sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Y con dos parámetros no basta?

Comment: Pasa que necesito que si el valor de la sucesión es mayor que N, este no lo imprima y el código no hace eso